# How to find bootnode IP Addresses for Ethereum testnet (Ropsten and Rinkeby)?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I am trying to develop a simple Voting app by following a tutorial on the net. I want to deploy my dapp to the testnet. To do this I am using the bootnodes as mentioned in the tutorial (below), but are there other bootnodes which can be used?

> mahesh@projectblockchain:~$ geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have the 2 official Ropsten nodes already.

As per the Geth code, in [`bootnodes.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/79b11121a7e4beef0d0297894289200b9842c36c/params/bootnodes.go#L23):

```
// TestnetBootnodes are the enode URLs of the P2P bootstrap nodes running on the
// Ropsten test network.
var TestnetBootnodes = []string{
    "enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303", // US-TX
    "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303", // IE
}

// RinkebyBootnodes are the enode URLs of the P2P bootstrap nodes running on the
// Rinkeby test network.
var RinkebyBootnodes = []string{
    "enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303", // IE
    "enode://343149e4feefa15d882d9fe4ac7d88f885bd05ebb735e547f12e12080a9fa07c8014ca6fd7f373123488102fe5e34111f8509cf0b7de3f5b44339c9f25e87cb8@52.3.158.184:30303",  // INFURA
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I already have the two nodes but was curious if there were others.